# Why is the picture in a tkinter button showing all black?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display an image in a tkinter button. However, the image appears to be completely black.

I have two images, 3 and 4 that are identical except for the color. If I show image 3, it works perfectly, but if I change it to 4, it does not work

[image]

This is how it looks with picture # 3:

[image]

and this is how it looks with picture #4:

[image]

It happens the same with any other image, and it works perfectly for that same image in any color but black.

My code is as follows:

```py
 self.bc_home = Image.open("images/4.png")    
 self.bc_homei = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.bc_home)
 self.homeb = tk.Button(self.planningUIL, image=self.bc_homei, command = 
 self.homep)
 self.homeb.image = self.bc_homei
 self.homeb.place(x=20, y=650)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about tkinter, but it sounds like this could be a problem with transparency. If you have the original PNGs in one directory, maybe create an HTML file with <html><body bgcolor=#808080><img src=1.png><img src=1.png><img src=1.png><img src=4.png></body></html> and if the black house (or any house) is filled with grey, there is a transparency issue tkinter needs to deal with. I suspect tk.Button has a transparency=True/False parameter to fix that.